# Error al instalar typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Estoy instalando typescript y cada vez que lo intento me da el mismo error, ya he usado vpn, revisado el proxy y nada.

Este es el error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g typescript
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.empresa.es
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kikic\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T12_51_21_907Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que dice el log de error completo?